Movie where older guitar player assesses that younger guitar player needs more soul
I've never seen the movie I'm asking about... but someone showed me a clip from it a few years ago.  I thought it would be easy to re-find, but keyword searches regarding guitars and producers didn't turn it up.
(...so perhaps the movie as a whole is not about guitars or producers, and it was just a scene?)
What happens is there's a kind of dim and smoky room where a harrowed rough old guy (maybe had a moustache?) gives audience to a younger guy for his guitar playing.  The younger guy does something very showy, but the older guy kind of shakes his head over it.  The older guy plays something slower and more emotional.
Sort of a "you're good... but you've got a lot to learn, kid" kind of thing.  Clip I saw was well-shot, and it was on YouTube... so I imagine it's well-known and not obscure.
It was in English, seemed certainly American. Saying I saw the clip on YouTube narrows it down to a 10 year window in terms of "when I saw the clip"...and it was in color. :-) But it was maybe... jeez. 3 years ago I saw it? "Modern moviemaking", in any case; it can't be that old.
Both were Caucasians. I believe they were playing electric guitar. I don't recall if the older guy had his own guitar... or if he took the guitar away from the kid after he was done playing. IIRC the kid played kind of a "shredding" style, showing off technical talent; and the older guy was trying to point out his weakness by playing something more punctuated and slow which was still technical. It was just the two of them in a room; I don't recall if it was a studio space.
I vaguely recall the movie title was two words long, like "THE PERFORMER" or something of that sort...

@Catija Hold me to the StackOverflow standards for "give me teh moviez" as we would for "give me teh codez", do you?  :-P  Fine, fine, turnabout is fair play.  Done; comments migrated.

What, being poor little low-views/low-questions "Movies & TV" doesn't mean we can't ask for quality in the questions that appear here? :P Particularly from someone who "knows better" :D Thanks!

@Catija Point is of course, you're right.

I'm just glad you answered, to be honest. Many people who come looking for films drop a question off and never return. Granted, you're on SE regularly, and that helps a lot. And I was teasing.

Near identical scene - Moscow on the Hudson, with Robin Williams on sax meeting a sax artist.

Actually, substitute the young man for a young woman and you'd have this scene from The Runaways.

I'm also looking for this movie but not find yet.
It was best music movie to me.
I remember the title of this movie was "JOY" or "Johny"..whatever "Jxxx.." in KOREA.
I saw this movie in KOREA at 1980's but usually the title of movie is not the original name in KOREA (That's why I can't find yet, if I'm not wrong..)
I will try to find this movie. and I hope my poor memory little bit help you to find this movie. If we find it someday, let's share the information.

It might be CROSSROADS:

Eugene is an extraordinary talent in classic guitar, but he dreams of being a famous Blues guitarist. So he investigates to find a storied lost song. He asks the legendary Blues musician Willie Brown to help him.


That sounds very familiar (the one-word title seems right, too).  The Wikipedia summary doesn't mention a scene fitting this description, but it does have some quotes up like "You might have a little bit of lightning in you, but you're missing everything else." -- which isn't coming from the scene I describe, but maybe that's thematic.  Maybe I'll have to find a copy of this movie!

Maybe Sweet and Lowdown? That was definitely not about electric guitar, it was acoustic, but maybe... http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158371/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Thanks for the attempt; but nope.  (That's one I've seen and it isn't it.)
